# When a collineation is a perspectivity?

Tags: projective-geometry

Veblen & Young, in "projective geometry", vol. 1, section 105, use the following lemma:

If a collineation between two intersecting planes in 3d projective space is such that any two corresponding lines intersect on the common line of the two planes,
then the collineation is a perspectivity.

Where one may find a proof?

Answer (score 1):

The common line $L$ of the two planes is preserved by the collineation $g$. Now, as it is where the intersection of any two corr. lines $\ell$ and $g(\ell)$ lies, each point on $L$ is preserved as well. But now you are still left with quite a bit of freedom ($GL_2$ acting on a 4-dimensional space).

Are you sure there are no more conditions there?

Comment: Thank you Dima! I think the same, however they an authority, so I preferred to check this. I believe quite a different theorem must be used.

Comment: perhaps you should spell out exactly what they mean by "corresponding lines" of a collineation.

Comment: On what page of the book it was used? (Sect 105 is 6 pages long...)